# How to find largest square of palindrome in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem where I am given a nXn square matrix of characters and I want to find out size of the largest palindrome square from this? The largest palindrome square is, a square with all rows and all columns as palindrome.

For eg.
Input

```
a g h j k
s d g d j
s e f e n
a d g d h 
r y d g s
```

The output will be:

```
3
```

corresponding to the middle square. I am thinking of dynamic programming solution but unable to formulate the recurrence relation. I am thinking the dimensions should be a(i,j,k) where i, j are the bottom-right of rectangle and k be the size of palindrome square. 
Can someone help me with the recurrence relation for this problem?

EDIT:

n<500, so I believe that I can't go beyond O(n^3).

Comment: you will probably also want a couple variables to record which column or row you are testing for a valid palindrome

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am stuck at, I want to do it in time complexity of O(n^3). I am still not able to get the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can solve the following problem:

- Ending at cell `(i, j)` is there any palindrome with different length horizontally and vertically.

Hint for above problem:

```java
   boolean[][][]palindrome;//Is there any palindrome ending at (i , j) has length k
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
           palindrome[i][j][0] = true;
           palindrome[i][j][1] = true;
           for(int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
               if(data[i][j - k + 1] == data[i][j] && palindrome[i][j - 1][k - 2])
                  palindrome[i][j][k] = true; 
       } 
  }
```

So, we can create two three dimensional arrays `int[n][n][n]col` and `int[n][n][n]row`.

For each cell(i, j), we will calculate the total number of palindrome with length k, ending at cell (0, j), (1, j) , ... (i, j) and total number of palindrome with length k, ending at cell (i,0), (i, 1), ... (i, j)

```java
for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    if(there is palindrome length k horizontally, end at cell (i, j)) 
       row[i][j][k] = 1 + row[i - 1][j][k];
    if(there is palindrome length k vertically, end at cell (i, j)) 
       col[i][j][k] = 1 + col[i][j - 1][k];
```

Finally, `if row[i][j][k] >= k && col[i][j][k] >= k` -> there is an square palindrome length k ending at (i,j).

In total, the time complexity will be **O(n^3)**

Comment: Really good solution. It worked. I curse myself every time, I am not able to solve a DP problem.

Comment: @Naman glad it help, you may just need some practice, don't worry :)

Comment: Thanks again. If you don't mind, can you please have a look at this problem also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863373/what-can-be-space-efficient-algorithm-for-single-row-of-skyscraper-puzzle  I could find the solution, but it is O(n^3). I just wanna know if it is possible in O(n^2)? Don't worry about the space complexity according to the problem description. I had asked that quite a long time ago.

Comment: @Naman you want to have a O(n^2) time complexity for above problem?

Comment: No, not for this problem. I have accepted this answer. I am asking for some other problem, it's the skypscrapper problem given in the link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863373/what-can-be-space-efficient-algorithm-for-single-row-of-skyscraper-puzzle

Comment: @PhamTrung can you please suggest how can I can  reduce memory ?

Answer (score 0):

lets start with the complexity of validating a palindrome:

A palindrome can be identified in `O(k)` where k is the length of the palindrome [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153433/complexity-of-palindrome-test)

you then want need to do that test 2k times once for each row and column in you r inner square. (using the length of the palindrome k, as the dimension)

so now you have `k * 2k -> O(2k^2) -> O(k^2)`

then you want to increase the possible search space to the whole data set `nxn` this is when a 2nd variable gets introduced

you will need to iterate over columns `1 to (n-k)` and all rows `1 to (n-k)` in a nested loop.

so now you have `(n-k)^2 * O(k^2) -> O(n^2 * k^2)`

Note: this problem is dependant on more than one variable

This is the same approach i suggest you take to coding the solution, start small and get bigger

Comment: That's the naive brute force approach, I am aware of that but I wanted to know if this can be done with dynamic programming in better than O(n^2 * k^2) (which is O(n^4) in worst case). I am sorry, I should edit the problem that I am not looking for the brute force approach.

Comment: fair enough, in that case you could consider checking every k'th row and column. then you only need test the rows columns between those when the edge rows / columns pass. Possibly storing the palindrome tests results in a 2D array

Comment: @Calcum Sorry I am unable to get you, can you please edit your answer with this new algorithm that you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Im sure there is probably a better way, and im pretty sure my logic is correct so take this at face value as its not tested.

Just to make the example easy im going to say that i,j is the top left corner or coordinates 1,1

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 a b c d e f g f 
2 d e f g h j k q 
3 a b g d z f g f 
4 a a a a a a a a
```

ie `(1,1) = a, (1,5) = e and (2,1) = d`

now instead of checking every column you could start by checking every kth column

ie when `k=3`

1) create a 2D boolean array the size of the character table all results TRUE

2) I start by checking column 3 `cfg` which is not a palindrome, thus I no longer need to test columns 1 or 2.

3) because the palindrome test failed marked the coresponding result in the 2D array (1,3) as FALSE (I know not to test any range that uses this position as it is not a palindrome)

4) Next check column 6, `fjf` which is a palindrome so I go back and test column 5, `ehz` != a palindrome

5) set (1,5) = FALSE

6) Then test column 8 then 7,

NOTE: You have only had to test 5 of the 8 columns.

since there were k columns in a row that were palindromes, now test the corresponding rows. Start from the bottom row in this case 3 as it will eliminate the most other checks if it fails

7) check row starting at (3,6) `fgf` = palindrome

8) check row starting at (2,6) `jkq` != a palindrome

9) set (2,6) = FALSE

10) check column starting at (2,3) `daa` != palindrome

11) set (2,3) = FALSE

Dont need to test any more for row 2 as both (2,3) and (2,6) are FALSE

Hopefully you can make sense of that.

Note: you would probably start this at `k = n` and decrement k until you find a result

Comment: I truly appreciate you for the help but I really cant make complete sense of all this. Because, 1) I need to find the largest such 'k', I am not given one. 2) I still feel your code is O(n^4) in worst case. I really can't take this at face value. I really don't believe that it's implementation can even reach till the value of n=200. In my case, I have to handle n<500